# Windows Phone 8.1 Geolocation Speed always 5.8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps, geolocation, windows-8.1

I am using Geoposition and a Postition changed event to grab Coordinates of the device location.

```
       private async void StartGpsMonitoring()
    {
        if (locator == null)
        {
            locator = new Geolocator();

        }
        if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            //throw new Exception();

            MessageDialog noGpsDialog = new MessageDialog("Location services are disabled, please enable location services");
            noGpsDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Location Settings", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler), 0));
            noGpsDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Cancel", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler), 1));
            await noGpsDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        if (locator != null)
        {
            //locator.MovementThreshold = 3;
            locator.ReportInterval = 1;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
            locator.PositionChanged +=
                new TypedEventHandler<Geolocator,
                    PositionChangedEventArgs>(locator_PositionChanged);
        }
    }

       private async void locator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speed = string.Empty;
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Geoposition geoPosition = e.Position;
            if (e.Position.Coordinate.Speed != null)
            {
                 speed = e.Position.Coordinate.Speed.Value.ToString(); // always 5.8
            }
            geolocation = geoPosition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString() + " " +
                              geoPosition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString() + "Speed = " +
                              speed;


            var textBlockStatus =
                ControlHelper.FindChildControl<TextBlock>(JourneyTrackerSection, "TextBlockStatus") as TextBlock;
            textBlockStatus.Text = geolocation;
        });
    }
```

I am also trying to get the speed value. But when using the emulator I am always getting 5.8 regardless of if I have speed limit/walking/biking set on the emulator, and still get 5.8 from a static position.

Can anybody shed some light as to why? Is it just the emulator? Would I get an accurate result if I used a real device?
Its hard to develop a location speed application where I have to run out side every time I want to debug/run it.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post some details as to what I have managed to find out in case anyone comes across this in the future. Looks like this is because it is running on the emulator. Managed to come across some limited details about using the geopositioning code and some details about it being hardware specific. After I have managed to get hold of a windows phone for testing the emulator cannot do the speed. Works perfect on an actual device.

This is extremely annoying by Microsoft. means that every time I need to test my app I have to go out driving. Rendering the GPS emulator completely useless!